# Trying to remove certain duplicate values in excel

Tags: excel, duplicates, unique-values

I have a data set of orders that are all linked by a primary key (batch number). However the order numbers have a field marking if they were on time or late. If one order number is marked late the whole batch number should be marked as late, and then remove the duplicate batch numbers. I am looking to do this in excel, formulas or VBA.

ie. starting result

```
   Batch Number      order Number     Late?
   1234              1                Late
   1234              2                Late
   1234              3                On Time
   5678              4                On Time
   5678              5                On Time
   5678              6                On Time
```

End Result

```
   Batch Number      order Number     Late?
   1234              2                Late
   5678              4                On Time
```

Thanks very much in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Will the "Late?" column always be either Late or On Time? or it has the possibilities of being something else?

Comment: How do you determine which order number should be taken when removing the duplicates?

Comment: @CedricGuindon This column will only have those two values

Comment: @Rawrplus it doesn't matter, as long as the batch number reflects the correct status in the "Late?" column

Answer (score 0):

Like this using a reference table

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$7=$E2),--($C$2:$C$7="LATE"))>0,"LATE","On time")
```

---

**Data**

[image: DATA]

---

**With VBA** replacing the existing values and returning unique rows:

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, key As Variant, dataRange As Range, dict As Object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("A2:C7")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rng In dataRange.Columns(1).Cells
        If Not dict.exists(rng.Value) Then
            dict.Add rng.Value, rng.Value
        End If
    Next rng

    For Each key In dict.keys
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(dataRange.Columns(1), key, dataRange.Columns(3), "Late") > 0 Then
            dict(key) = "Late"
        Else
            dict(key) = "On Time"
        End If
    Next key

    With dataRange
        .ClearContents
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(dict.Count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys)
        .Cells(1, 3).Resize(dict.Count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.items)
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

Version 2 To hide rows except for first instance of Late, if any late present, or On Time, if all On Time, for any given Batch Number.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, key As Variant, dataRange As Range, dict As Object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("A2:C7")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rng In dataRange.Columns(1).Cells
        If Not dict.exists(rng.Value) Then
            dict.Add rng.Value, rng.Value
        End If
    Next rng

    dataRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    For Each key In dict.keys
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(dataRange.Columns(1), key, dataRange.Columns(3), "Late") > 0 Then
            dict(key) = "Late"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(GetRowNumber(dataRange.Columns(3), key, "Late"), 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            dict(key) = "On Time"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(GetRowNumber(dataRange.Columns(3), key, "On Time"), 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next key

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Public Function GetRowNumber(ByRef rng As Range, ByVal key As Long, ByVal searchTerm As String) As Long
    Dim currentRng As Range
    For Each currentRng In rng.Rows
        If currentRng.Value = searchTerm And currentRng.Offset(, -2) = key Then
            GetRowNumber = currentRng.Row
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next currentRng
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to filter the table to only show the rows that have one batch number and the late status. Is it possible to use the advanced filtering feature on this?

Comment: Your question said to remove. You actually want to filter?

Comment: What do you want to remain in view and how does this fot with duplicates?

Comment: My apologies for not being more clear, yes filtering would be best. The end result table from my initial post is how I want to see the table. Im trying to get one batch number remaining, so if one order is late that should be the only entry for the batch number that remains. If they are all on time, then only one of those should remain.

Comment: A filter would not produce the desired result. Not without a helper column. The code could be re-written to leave only 2 rows with the appropriate late or on time showing and the other rows hidden.

Comment: I have written a version 2 above.